# addRow adds to top of listView correctly first time, then adds to bottom of the list

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I am taking a cursor from a listview on the bottom half of screen and adding it to the top half listView. This is working just not 100% as expected. The first time I click a bottom row it adds that row to the top listview at position 0 correctly and has the row that is there(this row exists when the app opens up) below it. Great, this is what I wanted, except for if I click another row from the bottomList. That row is added in the 2 position and not basically going to 0 and pushing the other 2 down.

Now, this is not correct for what I want and believe this is always messing up the onClick event I have as the data being passed from the topList being clicked is wrong now. Not sure if both are related so trying to at least get the topList to display correctly then I can debug more and see why the data being passed is not correct.

Here is the code I am using to update that topList with the cursor being passed from bottomList

```
    public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mTopCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    ListView mTopListView;
    public static MatrixCursor customCursor1;
    int flag = 0;
    TopListCursorAdapter mTopAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_list, container, false);
        String table = "employees";
        customCursor1 = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "Employee_number", "First_name",
                "Last_name", "Payroll_title", "ThumbnailData", "Email", "Phone_mobile", "Phone_office", "Cost_center_id",
                "Has_direct_reports", "Manager_employee_number"});
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        int mStartingEmployeeID = mStartingNumber;
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        mTopAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(mTopAdapter);
        customCursor1.close();
        db.close();
        return view;

    }

    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Employee_number")), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(11)});
            if (flag == 0) {
                customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{mTopCursor.getInt(0), mTopCursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Employee_number")), mTopCursor.getString(2),
                        mTopCursor.getString(3), mTopCursor.getString(6), mTopCursor.getString(9),
                        mTopCursor.getString(8), mTopCursor.getString(4), mTopCursor.getString(5),
                        mTopCursor.getString(10), mTopCursor.getString(7), mTopCursor.getString(11)});
                flag++;
            } else {
                flag = 1;
            }
            mTopAdapter.changeCursor(customCursor1);
            customCursor1.close();
        }
    }
}

public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public interface TopListClickListener {
        void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor);
    }

    private TopListClickListener mCallback;

    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        if(!(context instanceof TopListClickListener)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Content must implement BottomListClickListener");
        }
        this.mCallback = (TopListClickListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_top, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mTopCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopHomeScreenCV);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mPayrollTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mPayrollTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }


        final int position = cursor.getPosition();
        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Employee_number"));
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("First_name"));
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Last_name"));
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Payroll_title"));
                String mPic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ThumbnailData"));
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Email"));
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone_mobile"));
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone_office"));
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Cost_center_id"));
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Has_direct_reports"));
                String mManagerNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Manager_employee_number"));
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Manager_employee_number", mManagerNumber);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mTopCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onTopListClick(cursor);
                    Log.i("FROMCLICK", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mTopCardView;
    }
}

@Override
    public void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor) {
        Log.i("FistClickBeforePassing", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        BottomFragment bottomFragment = (BottomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
        bottomFragment.refreshList(cursor);
    }
```

Comment: You should not use cursor from passing data to the adapter, you can store the result from cursor in an array or a list and pass it to the adapter. Whenever you want  to update your listView you just need to update the array or list and then notify the adapter of the change by notifyDataSetChange method of the adapter.

Comment: Not sure why you can't pass a cursor when Android has an adapter that accepts a cursor? But how does this help me with my issue of the listview being populated from the bottom and not the top?

Comment: Sorry! my bad, I forgot about CursorAdapter, I thought you are using something like BaseAdapter of ListAdapter. but as @A.A said you don't need to create new adapter instance everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a new adapter every time you update your cursor. Use `mTopAdapter` as a member that you initialize in `onCreateView()` then update the cursor in your `update()` method using:

```
mTopAdapter.changeCursor(customCursor1);
mtopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Update**: To always keep the row from `mTopCursor` as the last row

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16440093/2070636), you can use [`MergeCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) to merge your `customCursor1` and `mTopCursor` into one new cursor to be used by the adapter:

```
public void update(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Employee_number")), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(11)});


        MergeCursor newCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {customCursor1, mTopCursor});
        mTopAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
        mtopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        customCursor1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your suggestion(see above). The first click is working just like before, now the second click isn't even showing that row into topList.

Comment: Try adding `mTopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Now each click after the first is working, but the same way. Just adding to the bottom of the list and not the top like the first click did.

Comment: I think it's because of your `if (flag == 0)` which is only called on the first update but not on any of the following ones causing the new rows to be added normally at the end

Comment: Was thinking the same, any suggestions on how to make the code in the flag last then? I need that row to be there already. But should be always on that last row in the list. Also don't want to keep creating it over and over as it's the same data.

Comment: I would highly recommend switching to `ArrayList<Employee>` to get better flexibility with data position, but if you really need to use cursors, then one way I can think of is to copy rows of `customCursor1` followed by that row from `mTopCursor` into a new cursor every time

Comment: If I place that into the method I get an error that it's attempting to access a closed CursorWindow. There is no line error so not sure where this is exactly happening. I have tried to comment the closing of customCursor1 and the cursor being passed into the update method with no luck. If I remove the MergeCursor line the app doesn't crash just goes back to the way the clicks aren't working as needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136262/discussion-between-a-a-and-adam-gardner).

Comment: added the last code we talked about, almost 100%. It's added the people right and the second click is on top finally, but now it's adding newCursor twice. So the more rows that get clicked, it is adding it twice.

Comment: Also now the cursor coming back is being added right but when clicked I am getting the wrong cursor back when I dump it to a String.

Comment: Can you share the code for your adapter and how you pass the cursor from the bottom fragment?

Comment: you said use an arrayAdapter, would that still be able to get the results? I mean if having issues with a CursorAdapter, not sure how using a different type of data structure or adapter would correct that.

Comment: Since I can use the code above now(just need new row on bottom) that works. But the problem is the cursor is being flipped around when I click on of the new rows. It gives me an employee_number of a different row. Not sure if I should accept your answer and just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter?

In my custom adapter, it looks something like this:

```
public void removeAllItems(MyDbHelper dbHelper)
    {
        //Go ahead and delete everything 
        ...
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

There are other similar options for changes that aren't huge, like this:

```
    notifyItemInserted(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mInjections.size());
```